# Plotly: How to show line for x and y axes with white background?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python

I'm using plotly while hiding the background

```
paper_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',
plot_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',
```

Unfortunatlly, reading the reference guide of the layout, I couldn't add the axis(only the xy lines on the left and the bottom.
Full code:

```
fig = px.box(pd_data, x="Epoch", y="Cosine similarity", color="Type",
            notched=True, # used notched shape
            title="Box plot of Cos similarity",
            hover_data=["Pair"] # add day column to hover data
            )

fig.update_layout(title_text="",
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
plot_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
              title_font_size=30)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shared a sample of your data, so I'll have to use a setup from [box-plots/](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/). In any case, all you should have to do is set `showline=True` for both axes like so:

```
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, x="time", y="total_bill", points="all")
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

fig.update_layout(title_text="",
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
                  title_font_size=30)

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with scatter plots that crossed (0, 0) - there are separate properties for the zero line.

I'm using plotly graph objects instead of plotly express here, but the axis update commands are the same.

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [x - 5 for x in range(10)]
y = x

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers'))

fig.update_layout(title_text="",
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,1)',\
                  title_font_size=30)

# this only updates the outer edges of the whole plot
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor="rgba(38,38,38,0.15)")
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor="rgba(38,38,38,0.15)")
fig.show()
```

displays the following:
[Gridded plot where X and Y axes are same as background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y3hI.png)

This is fixed by adding specifications for the zero line.

**Code:**

```
# this updates the actual x and y axes
fig.update_xaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=1, zerolinecolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=1, zerolinecolor='black')

fig.show()
```

displays the following:
[Gridded plot with black X and Y actual axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL4CO.png)

Obviously, setting the zerolinecolor to the same as the gridcolor would look prettier, it was just set to black for emphasis.