# Is there any way to add axis lines to a graph with Plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm currently making graphs with Plotly for publication, and I'm trying to display the axis lines, which I would expect is an easy and basic thing to do in a plot.

Take this dummy graph :

```
if (!require("plotly")) install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)

group <- c("a", "b", "c")
values <- c(0, 5, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, values)
plot <- df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~group, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "line") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(ticks = "outside"), xaxis = list(zeroline = TRUE))
plot
```

[image: Dummy plot]

I'm trying to add a vertical y-axis line that would interact with the ticks nicely. I thought that enabling a zero line with `zeroline = TRUE` in the `xaxis` call would work but it doesn't produce the "zeroline" because the data is categorical and there's no zero. The `inside` and `outside` options of the `ticks` call move around an invisible axis so that "zero" value must exist somehow.

Moving on, I then tried this vertical line function found on the web (there's an equivalent for horizontal lines) :

```
vline <- function(x = 0) {
  list(
    type = "line", 
    y0 = 0, 
    y1 = 1, 
    yref = "paper",
    x0 = x, 
    x1 = x, 
    line = list(color = "black", width = 1)
  )
}
```

[image: Dummy plot with vline]

It works, but it's clunky for multiple reasons :

1. When manually resizing the Viewer, the line behaves differently than the rest of the graph and doesn't stick to the axis ticks,
2. It goes a bit too low to be pretty,
3. The placement has to be fine-tuned manually, and (cf. point 1) has to be adapted each time the plot is resized,
4. It's a generally inelegant solution to something I thought would be straightforward.

Note that in my dummy example, there is a datapoint at 0. If there isn't one, then the x-axis zero line is gone too, which is another problem I have. But I suppose fixing one will fix the other.

I found nothing on the Plotly reference that would resemble a solution to this problem. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `showline` as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944207/8107362)

```
df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~group, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "line") %>% 
  layout(#yaxis = list(ticks = "outside"),
         xaxis = list(showline = TRUE), 
         yaxis = list(showline = TRUE,
                      zeroline = FALSE)
         )
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that was just as easy as I expected it to be... and yet I managed to miss it. Thanks !